# Can race conditions exist with TaffyDB and node.js?

Tags: node.js, taffydb

Can a race condition exist within TaffyDb and nodejs?
For example:
100 concurrent connections with node.js using require('net')
reliable data read relies on a variable Dbman(example) lock: to be 0 when not being read and 1 when being read. Could the data be read and therefor corrupted if 2 reads were called just before the lock to be set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js programs are JavaScript programs, and as-such, there is no multi-threading.

Each function runs from a SINGLE dispatch loop thread, so If you set a variable to a specific value it is guaranteed to remain that value through the whole execution of that function call.

While a single function is executing no other functions can run, therefore the race condition you are considering is impossible.